# Codeigniter links for search results

Tags: codeigniter

I'm a new to CodeIgniter and I have a problem when I display a list of items, I want each items to be a link, so when the user clicks that particular item, it will show the details of that item. Or perhaps give some suggestion on what I should google for. I have literally no idea whats terms or keywords that should I search about.

controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->getListOfAgent();                    
    }  

    function getListOfAgent()
    {
        $this->load->model("agentDB_model");

        $data['results'] = $this->agentDB_model->getAllAgentInfo();

        $this->load->view("viewAgent_view", $data);
    }




    function userInformation()
    {           
        //how to i get the selected item which the user clicked and show the details accordingly?

    }
}
```

model

```
<?php 

class agentDB_model extends CI_Model 
{
    function getAllAgentInfo()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user");

        return $query->result();
    }

    function addAgent($newAgent)
    {
        $this->db->insert("user", $newAgent);
    }

}
```

view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <p>List Of Agent in database</p>
    </div>

    <?php
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            echo "<a href = 'Site/userInformation'>$row->userName</a>";

            echo "</br>";   
            echo "</br>";   
        }



        //$this->load->controller(Site/userInformation);
    ?>


    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2012 basicsite.com</p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the `Site/userInformation` method for what record you want the information. You use [URI segments](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) for this.

So, in your view, change the following line:

```
echo "<a href = 'Site/userInformation'>$row->userName</a>";
```

to:

```
echo "<a href = 'Site/userInformation/$row->userID'>$row->userName</a>";
```

Then, in your controller method, add the parameter to the method declaration:

```
function userInformation($userID)
{           
    // now, you use the model to get the correct record from the db based on 
    // the $userID and display the information
}
```

Comment: In order to display the information, OP needs another view page, and they need to load that view page from the method `userInformation` in the controller, don't they?

Comment: @CrescentMoon - Yes, they would need another view in that method to dictate the presentation to the user. From the given code, the OP knows how to display a view and pass it data. The issue was how to get the correct data in which to pass to the view.

Comment: Hmmm, but it seems more like our OP got this code from somewhere over the net and trying to understand the basics behind it, as they've already mentioned they're new to CI. As for that, I highly doubt they fully understand how to create a view and pass data to it. A little more help in your solution can be more convenient.

Comment: @CrescentMoon - OK, but the purpose of SO is not to write code for the OP, but to answer the question posed. You're welcome to write a more thorough answer if you feel it necessary.

Comment: Can I edit your answer just a bit?? I don't want to write code, just want to show the OP the basic structure? Is it ok?

Comment: @CrescentMoon - Yes, feel free!

Comment: @CresentMoon I know how to create views and models just the concept of getting the selected item to be shown... And thanks for your help and feedbacks guys.